# How can I change the values in a particular column that are equal to a given value?

Tags: r, dataframe

`data_active` is any dataset.

Ideally when the condition is satisfied, the values must be changed. But when I execute this code, it is changing the values in each of the specified columns to the values given in the `if` statement.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data_active))
{
 if(data_active[i,1]==4866)
 {
  data_active$St="MH" 
  data_active$Reg="South Central" 
  data_active$REGION="South"
  data_active$Market="86"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to get used to a 'thinking with R' mentality. You don't need for loops or if statements. You can do this with just one line of code.

Try the following (replace id with your column name):

```
data_active[data_active$id == 4866,c("St","Reg","REGION","Market")] <- c("MH","South Central", "SOUTH", "86")
```

First, this statement is finding the rows where id matches 4866, and selecting from them the columns in the list created by c.

```
data_active[data_active$id == 4866,c("St","Reg","REGION","Market")]
```

Secondly, it is setting the values of these columnns to a new list, containing the values you desire.

```
<- c("MH","South Central", "SOUTH", "86")
```

Comment: As a caveat, there would be problems with this approach were the replacement values not all string (as they are here).

Answer (score 3):

Inside your `if` statement, you have assigned a value to the entire column, not just to the row indicated by `i`. To assign to just a specific row, you need to assign to just that element of the vector.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data_active))
{
 if(data_active[i,1]==4866)
 {
  data_active$St[i]="MH" 
  data_active$Reg[i]="South Central" 
  data_active$REGION[i]="South"
  data_active$Market[i]="86"
 }
}
```

That said, this is not the idiomatic way to do this in `R`. More natural would be to use logical indexing.

```
data_active$St[data_active[,1]==4866]="MH" 
data_active$Reg[data_active[,1]==4866]="South Central" 
data_active$REGION[data_active[,1]==4866]="South"
data_active$Market[data_active[,1]==4866]="86"
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to indicate which row's values to change.  Otherwise, *all* rows will be given new values every time `data_active[i,1]==4866`.

Try this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data_active))
{
 if(data_active[i,1]==4866)
 {
  data_active$St[i]="MH" 
  data_active$Reg[i]="South Central" 
  data_active$REGION[i]="South"
  data_active$Market[i]="86"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost identical to Ina solution, but works for columns with different types as well (see Brian Diggs comment to Ina solution).

```
data_active[data_active$id == 4866,
            c("St","Reg","REGION","Market")] <- list("MH","South Central", "SOUTH", "86")
```